# RHEL: what default repos for /etc/yum.repos.d/

Tags: repository, yum, rhel

I have a fresh installation of RHEL6 in front of me. For some reason there are no repo files in /etc/yum.repos.d/

What are the default repos to use so I can install packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download software, updates, and security errata, your system should be registered to RHN.
For further information, have a look at these pages:

- [How do I access RHN Classic to download software, updates, and security errata?](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/node/5023)
- [Red Hat Network (RHN) Frequently Asked Questions](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/node/15979)
- [What is Yum and how do I use it?](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/node/9934)